# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error while converting to datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime-format

I have this format date:

```
"Tue Mar 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"
```

This is from this input type:

```
<input type="date" name="transaction_date" ng-model="masterlist.transaction_date">
```

I've been trying these but got this error - `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(transaction_date, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How will I convert this to datetime format since I need to add this to the database and datetime is the format.

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
transaction_date = transaction_date.Replace("GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)", "").Trim();
var formated = DateTime.ParseExact(transaction_date, "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Remove the GMT part and then parse the date time, Since the extra string has the characters M, s, d the parser breaks.

Comment: do you want this `GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)` part in your formatted datetime as well?

Comment: It was part of the input type i made

Comment: is the part `GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)` always constant?

Comment: Yes, it is always present.

Comment: So better we can strip it off during conversion and proceed right?

Comment: Yes, and how I am gonna do it?

Comment: its a string trim, it must work fine. I tested the above code in my machine. your `transaction_date` is a string right??

Comment: Yes, having this value "Tue Mar 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"

Comment: I wonder what else might be the issue, I am using the same code in my POC and it seems to work fine.